# Kinect V1, setting up environment

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I never tried working on a kinect before, and the kinect I have is the first version that was for the Xbox 360. So most of the resources online on how to even start keep giving me errors, so if you have any resource or just tell me how to set up the environment i will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The [1.8 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40278) for the Kinect is still available. Also for a simple API you should look into [Virtruvius](https://github.com/LightBuzz/Vitruvius). But make sure you have the suitable adapters etc.